# Why is the app closing suddenly without showing any error?

Tags: android

**What my app does?** The app is selecting a photo from photos Gallery.

**What is my problem?** Once I select the photo from gallery it closes up without error.

**What I have done?** I've increased the memory of the device and it didnt function. I took it out from proyect and the activity worked fine, it came back to the activity.

**What is the main problem?** It doesn't function on the proyect and I cant tell why.

**Wold you like to see what is happening?** Here is a video. First when it closes up, and second when I do it from another project and works fine.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SntnyKiJQ1Q&feature=youtu.be

---

**EDIT**

My problem was that once I choose the picture from the gallery there was no activity on the stack.

**Why?**

The problem was on manifest's **android:noHistory="true"** tag, as there was no history the gallery couldn't find any activity and it closed the app.

---

The code:

The Intent I use to open the gallery and select a photo:

```
public void openGallery(int req_code){

   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setType("image/*");
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select file to upload "), req_code);
}
```

The onActivityResult where I get the data which is never called because it closes up:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE1)
        {
            selectedPath1 = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("selectedPath1 : " + selectedPath1);
        }
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE2)
        {
            selectedPath2 = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("selectedPath2 : " + selectedPath2);
        }
        tv.setText("Selected File paths : " + selectedPath1 + "," + selectedPath2);
    }
}
```

The logcat:

```
01-05 15:18:14.569: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent {   act=android.intent.action.UPLOADIMAGEDEMO cmp=com.example/.UploadImageDemo }
01-05 15:18:15.779: D/dalvikvm(2496): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2697 objects / 189152 bytes in 92ms
01-05 15:18:16.599: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.example/.UploadImageDemo: 1953  ms (total 1953 ms)
01-05 15:18:21.899: D/dalvikvm(279): GC_EXPLICIT freed 871 objects / 134112 bytes in 217ms
01-05 15:18:26.620: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent {  act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras) }
01-05 15:18:28.250: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent {  act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=image/* flg=0x3000000  cmp=com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery }
01-05 15:18:28.670: D/dalvikvm(279): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 388 objects / 53352 bytes in 60ms
01-05 15:18:28.850: D/dalvikvm(279): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 326 objects / 90664 bytes in 53ms
01-05 15:18:29.200: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity    com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery: 873 ms (total 2345 ms)
01-05 15:18:29.420: D/dalvikvm(279): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 725 objects / 106960 bytes in 140ms
01-05 15:18:30.430: W/InputManagerService(59): Starting input on non-focused client         com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@45020da8 (uid=10002 pid=279)
01-05 15:18:32.010: D/dalvikvm(112): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9994 objects / 476368 bytes in 149ms
```

I hope the community can help me!!

Comment: +1 for the video! Have you also tried it on a real device?

Comment: This is not the right part of the logcat output.  Run your app from the IDE until it crashes, then search logcat for "exceeds budget".  If you find it, please post the relevant part.  Oh, and +1 for the video too...

Comment: Chris I tried from a real device and it Kept happening. Simon, I found the reason and post it below. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok Guys, first of all thank you very much for your answers, they helped me to keep going today..

The problem was on manifest's **android:noHistory="true"** tag, as there was no history the gallery couldn't find any activity and it closed the app.

Again, thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

// Sorry, don't have enough reputation to comment accepted answer, but I guess my case will be helpful for others with the same issue

I had exactly the save issue in code written by another developer and struggled with it for a couple of days. But there was no android:noHistory attribute in manifest, but activity was launched with the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY.

Like this:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

I googled for it for hours, reached this SO question twice, but found out an answer only when decided to search my whole project for word "history".

Answer (score 0):

Normally Android applications will get crashed if we are trying to load pictures as bitmap/drawable of huge size (depending upon heap memory allocated by os); for eg: 1mb sized images or more.

Try loading small sized images, and check whether the problem persist.
Normally crash happens at code related to BitmapFactory.* .

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
       R.drawable.android);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help body I found the actual answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what exactly is wrong cause trace does not contain any exception message. But I can share piece of code:

**launch Intent**

```
private final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 0;

private void runGallery() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
}
```

**handle result**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedPictureUri = data.getData();
        loadGalleryAttachment(selectedPictureUri);
    }
}

private void loadGalleryAttachment(Uri uri){
    if (uri != null) {
        String path = getPath(uri);
        File f = new File(path);
        // do something with picture file   
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
      int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } 
}
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Vyacheslav thank you for your help I found the answer to my question.