# My application closes - android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android

EDIT: GIF image has been corrected.
EDIT 2: I've just reproduced it with a Samsung skin on AVD!!!

This is the error:

> 06-30 14:16:03.695 8220-8220/ar.com.plw.commonwealth E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: ar.com.plw.commonwealth, PID: 8220
>                                                                          android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c0000
>                                                                              at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
>                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.getInteger(Resources.java:1055)
>                                                                              at ar.com.plw.commonwealth.tabs.OstTabFragment.onCreateView(OstTabFragment.java:75)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1984)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
>                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
>                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
>                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
>                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:676)
>                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:479)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
>                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
>   06-30 14:16:03.695 8220-8220/ar.com.plw.commonwealth E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
>                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
>                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
>                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
>                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

And this is the exact code where it happens:

```
        Resources resources = getResources();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    if (resources.getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet)) {
        //on the following line application crashes.
        mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(resources.getInteger(R.integer.columns), StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL); 
    } else {
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    }
```

Some people told me my application closes on item tap. It is a RecyclerView. Unfortunately, i could not reproduce this issue with my devices nor emulators.

It is just closing the app, not showing any error.

A nice user send me this GIF:
[image]

this is my on click listener:

```
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, TabActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("title", filteredItems.get(position).title);
            b.putString("playlist", filteredItems.get(position).playlist);
            imageView.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap image = imageView.getDrawingCache();
            b.putParcelable("imageBitmap", image);
            intent.putExtras(b);

            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This is my oncreate of the tab activity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    title = b.getString("title");
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) b.getParcelable("imageBitmap");
    TextView tabTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tabTitle);
    ImageView coverImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tabImage);
    coverImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    tabTitle.setText(title);
    tabTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    //banners
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequestBanner = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBanner);

    // Google Analytics
    AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
    mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();

}
```

Did anybody know what could be happening?
i've checked in my manifest if i got `android:noHistory="true"`, just as sugested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243794/why-is-the-app-closing-suddenly-without-showing-any-error), but i didn't have the "history" word in my entire project.

Regards,

Comment: do you use acra?

Comment: no. Actually, i did not even know about it

Comment: Did you check log? Perhaps post it.

Comment: i could not, because i can't reproduce it. I've been thinking that all issues comes from Samsung devices.

Comment: hey guys, i've just reproduced the issue with Samsung skin on AVD. I'll edit my post right away